# Processing can't access built in webcam

Tags: processing

I’ve written the following code and I get error an error

> ```
> IllegalStateException: Could not find any devices
> ```

```
import processing.video.*;
Capture unicorn;

void setup(){
    size(640,480);
    unicorn=new Capture (this,640,480);
    unicorn.start();
    background(0);
}

void captureEvent(Capture video){
    video.read();
}

void draw(){
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        float x=random(width);
        float y=random(height);
        color c=unicorn.get(int(x),int(y));
        fill(c);
        noStroke();
        ellipse(x,y,16,16);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check that you can use your camera with another software? In [this post](https://discourse.processing.org/t/processing-cant-find-built-in-camera/27544) someone shares some code to list the available cameras, does your device appears when you run the code? In [this post](https://discourse.processing.org/t/processing-cant-find-the-camera-video-libraries-dont-work/25128) there are a few things people try which seem to help, have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Just to be sure: did you add the video library for Processing already (it is the library named "Video | GStreamer-based video library for Processing.")? Installation is explained in step 1 of this [Processing video tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/video/), which contains much more interesting information and great video examples. Since you are able to run your sketch, this should already be okay.

As [statox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4194289/statox) already mentioned, be sure that the camera is working for other programs; there might be some hardware or driver issue. To list the cameras that Processing can detect, you can use code from the [Capture documentation](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/video/Capture.html). This is only the part for showing the available cameras; use the link for the complete example:

```
import processing.video.*;

String[] cameras = Capture.list();

if (cameras.length == 0) {
  println("There are no cameras available for capture.");
} else {
  println("Available cameras:");
  for (int cameraIndex = 0; cameraIndex < cameras.length; cameraIndex++) {
    println(cameras[cameraIndex]);
  }
}
```

On my system with two cameras, the output looks like this:

```
Processing video library using GStreamer 1.16.2
Available cameras:
<Camera 1>
<Camera 2>
```

If the code from the Capture documentation does not work for you, you can try this alternative approach suggested by [Neil C Smith on the Processing forum](https://discourse.processing.org/t/processing-cant-find-the-camera-video-libraries-dont-work/25128/12) (was already mentioned by statox):

```
import processing.video.*;

Capture camera;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480);

  // Suggestion from Neil C Smith on the Processing forum:
  camera = new Capture(this, "pipeline:autovideosrc");
  camera.start();     
}

void draw() {
  if (camera.available()) {
    camera.read();
  }

  image(camera, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: it says no cameras available for capture. But I don't understand how that is possible because I have a built in webcam on my laptop.

Comment: Are you able to use the webcam in other applications? (Using, for example, the [Camera application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-the-camera-in-windows-10-8da044ed-c4a8-2fb4-da51-232362e4126d) for Windows or the [Cheese application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese_(software)) for Linux.)

Comment: yes I can access my camera that way from the camera application but not through processing

Comment: That's very strange. You could uninstall and reinstall the Processing video library. If that doesn't help, you could try a fresh install of Processing (by installing the latest version if you're on an older version or installing an older version otherwise). If you have another laptop, you could try installing Processing and the video library on that one and test it there.